# Ethereum private network: Operation not permitted

Tags: ubuntu, blockchain, ethereum, geth

I created my genesys block and successfully connected me (admin node) to the network once. Now that I try to connect again, as I geth --datadir 'mychaindata' command, everything runs smoothly until I hit the

```
 Starting P2P Networking
 RLPx listener up
```

Then everything closes :
     Blockchain manager stop
     Stopping Ethereum Protocol
     Ethereum Protocol stop
etc... Until error message:

```
 Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen unix /mnt/c/Users/J-
 C/AppData/Roaming/myGethBlockchain/mychaindata/geth.ipc: bind: operation 
 not permitted
```

I am running it on bash Ubuntu on Windows but as I said, it worked once... And connecting to Ethereum main blockchain also works!

Comment: Probably better suited to SuperUser, as this isn't programming-related.

Comment: Did not even know about that website, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Unix socket can't be created in sharefs, set the datadir to Unix fs like `/home/datadir`

Comment: Indeed. It was my mistake. I am running it on Windows, but in a Ubuntu command line. Therefore I had to specify the directory to the IPC (which you don't have to do on Windows, but on Linux / Mac).